# Will creating a shortcut/favorite for my network drive instead of using a mapped drive help prevent encryption by ransomware?

Tags: malware, attack-prevention

For security reasons and the prevention of spread of Malware over the network, is creating a Desktop Shortcut or Internet Explorer favourite considered safer than a Mapped Drive?

Answer (score 6):

### No and Yes

---

**No**:

> Law #1: If a bad guy can persuade you to run his program on your computer, it's not your computer anymore

[10 Immutable Laws of Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722487.aspx)

Ultimately, if it's running on your system, malware has (at least) the same level of access to your file system, and those of networked resources, as you do. So, strictly speaking, it won't matter whether a file share is "mapped" or linked through a shortcut - if you have access to it, the malware ***can*** get to it too.

---

**Yes:**

*The key word in the above paragraph: **can**.*

Just because malware *can* do something, doesn't mean it *will*. Unless you're dealing with an attacker that's specifically targeting you or your organization, the majority of malware you'll encounter is going to be from generic toolkits engineered to optimize effectiveness across the largest possible number of targets. In short, *most malware is generic*.

It is relatively easy, and generally more valuable on the majority of targets, for malware to just look for mounted drives to infect. If a resource is already mounted in the OS, it's a fair bet that it's within close reach (i.e.: low latency) and that you've got at least some level of access to it. Searching all devices on the local network for drives that will allow the malware to have read/write access is a much more complex and time-consuming matter, and generally much less likely to bear fruit. It's also a lot "noisier", and therefore more likely to be caught by corporate monitoring systems.

This is *very* commonly seen with ransomware. Most ransomware will (on a Windows system) simply run through all the lettered drives (e.g.: local hard drives, local removable media, mapped network drives) and encrypt whatever it finds in those areas that matches the file types it's made to target. Resources that aren't linked to a drive letter usually won't get touched. So, for ransomware and other malware that behaves similarly, there certainly is a benefit to avoiding mapped network drives.

It is certainly still possible for malware to discover network shares you're connected to even when they're not mapped to a drive letter. To see this in action (for Windows systems), manually browse to a non-mapped network share in File Explorer and then run `net use` at a command prompt. You'll see the resource you're connected to in that list, with no letter associated.

That said, avoiding networked drive mappings still offers a certain amount of defense against this sort of discovery. To be most useful, mapped drives have to be *persistent* - that is, the connection is re-established on system startup and it is maintained until you explicitly destroy it. The connection that is made when you follow a desktop shortcut is more transient, though - at most, it will usually only last until the next reboot. So, while it is not impossible for malware to discover this connection it will generally reduce the likelihood of it happening.

---

**TL;DR:**

Strictly speaking, once you have malware running on your system it can do whatever it wants to do with resources you have access to - regardless of whether or not they're "mapped".

However, in practice, most malware that you will see is simply going after "low-hanging fruit". So, it will not usually be made to go very far beyond whatever resources your system has mounted at the time of infection. If you avoid using network drive mappings, you substantially reduce the likelihood that there will be a connection for malware to discover when it runs. If you happen to get hit with something that *only* looks for "drive letters", the impact is *completely isolated* to the local system.

So, while it may be far from foolproof, there is still some security value in staying away from mapping network drives. In many ways, it's like [using a non-default port for common network services](https://danielmiessler.com/blog/security-and-obscurity-does-changing-your-ssh-port-lower-your-risk/). It's a low-effort, *additional* layer, that you can add to your security posture to obtain potentially high value. (Emphasis on *additional* because, again, this is not foolproof. You also should have other, more reliable security measures in place to prevent malware infections and isolate their impact.)

Comment: You have to assume that malware will do anything and everything it can when it has access to a system, period. Saying that most malware goes after "low-hanging fruit" is an incredibly dangerous proposition to base information security on. When millions of dollars are at stake and patient's medical records or banking information are at risk, take the conservative approach and hope like hell that that's enough

Comment: @VerbalKint This is why I say, at least a couple times, that this security measure is *not foolproof*. You should most certainly, and should *already* have much stronger access control measures in place. Read the article I linked, and others on Daniel Meissler's website, about using obscurity as a security layer (which this is). Obscurity is nearly never bad in a security system, so long as it's not the entirety of your security system.

Comment: To paraphrase [Meissler's oft-used analogy on the subject](https://danielmiessler.com/study/security-by-obscurity/): *A tank's armor is not made weaker (nor stronger) by camouflage. But the tank is much less likely to be targeted with it than without.* There's *always* value in reducing the likelihood that your systems will be targeted - or, in this case, reducing the likelihood that a malware or ransomware infection on one device will have immediate and broad effect on your whole network.

Answer (score 2):

### **No.**

Does this actually protect against all attacks? Absolutely not. Might it prevent some? Probably not. Is it worth the inconvenience to the user? No. Does it make any sense to do this anyway in the off chance that you have an inept attacker? No.

It doesn't really matter. If malware has access to your system, and your system has access to a network drive, then malware has access to the network drive. A desktop shortcut is just a file path to your network drive, which is essentially the same as a mapped drive.

Now, if in mapping a drive you set your machine to remember network credentials, malware might be able to get those credentials and reconnect at a later time or connect to the network drive automatically, whereas a shortcut might prompt you every time for network credentials. But in both cases this behavior could be changed, and you can never trust the client.

**Why it does not matter:**

Whether it is a desktop shortcut or a mapped drive, the problem has nothing to do with when/how the operating system connects to a drive. Both shortcuts and mapped drives point to network paths, which are accessible to the operating system. If the infected user has write access to a network drive, malware can upload malicious payloads to the network drive and wait for unsuspecting users to click on them and infect their own machines.

If you are concerned about the network drive acting as a staging area of sorts for malicious files, there are other steps you can take to secure it. Whitelist files types, set read/write permissions for different user accounts with different access levels according to the principal of least permission, or combine the above with an internal firewall (as you've mentioned you have) and antivirus solution.

**Why doing this for edge cases is ludicrous (addressing ransomware specifically):**

Saying that this is a valid security measure is completely false. Nor is the possible inconvenience to the user justified, even taking the conservative approach of locking down absolutely everything. And considering how advanced modern ransomware attacks are, I would highly doubt that a malicious program looking to encrypt files is going to stop at connected drives. More likely, it will check every file and path on the local machine, and every available network drive and path, regardless of how they are mounted to the operating system. **If your computer can access network drives and ransomware has access to your computer, ransomware can and will access your network drives, and if it has write permissions, could encrypt files on them.**

**Anything than can go wrong will go wrong. When it comes to security, always assume the worst.**

Comment: Thank you Verbal much appreciated, Users require access to a shared drive for a system sitting behind an internal firewall by mapping the drive, my concern isnt access more of spread of malware, are there any alternatives or better ways that may help prevent the possibilty of this occuring...I thought that a mapped drive connection would be persistent where as a shortcut or favourit in a browser only became active once the shortcut was click and explorer open i.e. preventing a permanenet connection.

Comment: @Luke, see my edited answer. Put simply, access implies spread. If malware can access something, it can spread to it. If it has write access to the network drive, it can copy payloads and malicious files to the drive and wait for unsuspecting users to click on them and spread the malware. It depends on what permissions the computers that connect to the drive use/have set. Shortcuts vs mapped drives isn't really a concern.

Comment: If I answered your question, if you could mark my post as the answer, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: This answer relies on the flawed premise that malware *will* operate on everything that you or your system has access to. In practice, this does not happen with many common infections. Using a desktop shortcut instead of a drive mapping, in this regard, is very much like running a network service on a non-standard port. It doesn't make you immune to attack, but it will help dodge a substantial number of them. So, while it should not be relied upon as your only security measure, there is still some value in it.

Comment: It's not a flawed premise. Traversal is the very nature of crypto malware and touching everything you have access to is its only purpose; the strain one of my last employers caught in 2013 did in fact traverse shortcuts to any network resource it could enumerate, including browser bookmarks. A shortcut might be an effective countermeasure against your mom finding your porn but in practice it does for malware what prayer does for contraception.

Comment: @Ivan, that was one of the most brilliant defenses to a comment I have ever had the privilege of reading, thank you. Granted, my answer does take the conservative approach in assuming that anything that can go wrong will, but in no way is the premise itself flawed. Rather, it is fundamental to information security. He also states that "It doesn't make you immune to attack, but it will help dodge a substantial number of them". I think this is completely false. The number is not substantial, but insignificant, and certainly not enough to justify the possible inconvenience for the user.